# How to change the sequence of the legend in chartJs PIE Chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

### I have Created a Pie chart using ChartJs. There has legend in follwing order

- Maths
- Science
- ICT

### But I want to change it to

- ICT
- Maths
- Science

Have any way to do that?

Here is the **Config** part in PIE chart ...........

```
    {
  dataRequest: [],// data has here
  config: [{                                                              
      legend: {display: true, position: 'right'},
      responsive: false,  
      plugins: { datalabels: { display: false } },
      tooltips: {
        enabled: false
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one can help -
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html?h=reverse

"reverse" key does the job